# One Click Installer for Console Application .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple console application written in .NET. I need to make an installer for the console application and put it in the server directory. This can be achieved by using the Setup Project in MS Visual Studio. I also want the ability that whenever I open the app it checks for a new version. If the new version exists then it installs it. Any recommendations on how to achieve this in .NET?

Comment: So your question is really about checking for new versions?

Comment: Not really checked for new versions! I remember that for my Windows Forms app it somehow automatically did that after installation. When the user clicks on the Windows Forms app and there was a new version it prompts the user to install the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClickOnce handles versioning for you. Simply publish new versions to the same place as previous versions, and when the user starts the app they will receive notice of the new version. That's part of the whole point of ClickOnce. The downside is, you lose control over the location of your application in the user's filesystem (for a simple console app like yours, that's probably not a huge deal, but I'll leave that decision to you). We've also had difficulty with certificates; if you sign your ClickOnce manifests (strongly recommended) you have to keep exactly the same certificate, strongly identifiable from a major CA, to keep the ClickOnce process strictly "click once".

Pretty much the only other way to handle versioning is to implement some web service that will report the most current version, and have your app call that service on startup to notify the user of upgrades. The upside is that your users still control where the app goes, and you can control where the app is published (if the next version needs to go on a different server, no problem; just point the user there using some information returned by the web service). The downside is more work for you to develop and deploy.